# Symmetric decrypting returns a NULL value

Tags: sql-server, encryption, encryption-symmetric, isqlquery

I have two databases . I copied all the data from one table and inserted into another database table . I have created symmetric key on second database but when i try to run  the query as follow

```
 OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = N'StrongPassword';        
 select DecryptByKey(columname) as DocSSN from tablename
 CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SecureSymmetricKey;
```

but allway return null value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the steps described in [Create Identical Symmetric Keys on Two Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366281.aspx). You will have to re-encrypt all the data on both servers/databases with a newly created symmetric key that uses the given known key material. Creating a key copy after the fact is not possible.

Sharing symmetric keys between servers/databases is a very bad practice. You should encrypt with different keys on each database.